# Why phpmyadmin refuses to connect over localhost but accepts 127.0.0.1?

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, localhost, macos-sierra

I just updated my mac to 10.13 and reinstalled my dev tools. While setting up phpmyadmin it was unable to connect to mysql using:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

phpmyadmin throws:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

instead I had to use to get it working:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

In the past I could leave the default "localhost" and had no issues but it won't connect via socket any more.

My mysql user is 'root'@'localhost', using latest mysql, apache, phpmyadmin.

What could be the reason?
Thanks

Comment: Check what localhost is pointing to.  Maybe it is pointing to your IP which is not reachable for some reason.  I see this problem come up often when doing Android work locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @N00b Pr0grammer's suggestion, I went trough the different solution still I figured it out.

On fresh installs of OS X, php.ini is turned off, and by default looks for mysqli.default_socket at "/var/mysql/mysql.sock" so I had to 1. rename `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` than 2. set:

```
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and restart apache. Now phpmyadmin is able to connect to mysql via localhost as well.

Comment: Plus one for your effort!

Answer (score 4):

There can be more than one reason for this to happen and the same has been discussed on this question as well. I suggest that you go through the answers provided on this question to resolve the error based on your environment that you hold.

This is the [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1)!

The common problem that I tend to see in dev environments is this:

You may have `IPv6` enabled, its very possible localhost resolves to the `IPv6` localhost, that is not defined in your `MySQL` config.

Comment: It's on macOS, so IPv6 is pretty much always on (and tends to be tried before IPv4). Service not listening on IPv6 is a really common cause of problems like this.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Had to change `mysqli.default_socket` to `/tmp/mysql.sock` inside php.ini.